# How to format numbers in a percent pie chart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts5

Using one of the official demos for a simple pie chart, how can I reformat all percent numbers? Say, I want to have all numbers rounded. I tried anything from putting `numberFormat` properties on pretty much everything to global `root.numberFormatter.set("numberFormat", "#,###");` to no avail. Any hints?

```html
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/percent.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
am5.ready(function() {

// Create root element
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");


// Set themes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);


// Create chart
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/
var chart = root.container.children.push(am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
  layout: root.verticalLayout
}));


// Create series
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Series
var series = chart.series.push(am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
  valueField: "value",
  categoryField: "category",
  numberFormatter: am5.NumberFormatter.new(root, {numberFormat: "###"}),
}));


// Set data
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Setting_data
series.data.setAll([
  { value: 10, category: "One" },
  { value: 9, category: "Two" },
  { value: 6, category: "Three" },
  { value: 5, category: "Four" },
  { value: 4, category: "Five" },
  { value: 3, category: "Six" },
  { value: 1, category: "Seven" },
]);


// Play initial series animation
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/#Animation_of_series
series.appear(1000, 100);

}); // end am5.ready()
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: to format the numbers in a percent pie chart in amCharts 5, you can use the `numberFormatter` property of the `PieSeries` to set a number format for the values. In this case, you can use the `toFixed()` method to round the numbers to a certain number of decimal places.

Comment: Thanks @StefanIordache do you have an example? According to the documentation, `numberFormatter` has to be an instance of `am5.NumberFormatter` which I tried to set like `numberFormatter: am5.NumberFormatter.new({NumberFormat: '###'})` which gives an `Object.ts:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: Ah, i forgot the root parameter, changed it: `numberFormatter: am5.NumberFormatter.new(root, {numberFormat: "###"})` Now there's no error but numbers are not formatted anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [per the documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/pie-series/), you can set the label text template of a series using this:

```
series.labels.template.set("text", 
    "{category}: [bold] {valuePercentTotal.formatNumber('0.00')}%[/] ({value})");
```

For the number format you can enter `#.` to get the rounded percentages. See the working snippet:

```html
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/percent.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
am5.ready(function() {

// Create root element
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");


// Set themes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);


// Create chart
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/
var chart = root.container.children.push(am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
  layout: root.verticalLayout
}));


// Create series
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Series
var series = chart.series.push(am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
  valueField: "value",
  categoryField: "category",
  numberFormatter: am5.NumberFormatter.new(root, {numberFormat: "###"}),
}));

series.labels.template.set("text", 
    "{category}: [bold] {valuePercentTotal.formatNumber('#.')}%[/] ({value})");
        
// Set data
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Setting_data
series.data.setAll([
  { value: 10, category: "One" },
  { value: 9, category: "Two" },
  { value: 6, category: "Three" },
  { value: 5, category: "Four" },
  { value: 4, category: "Five" },
  { value: 3, category: "Six" },
  { value: 1, category: "Seven" },
]);


// Play initial series animation
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/#Animation_of_series
series.appear(1000, 100);

}); // end am5.ready()
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Sure, you could do that if you have the valuePercentTotal which I don't. I have absolute numbers which the percent pie series converts to percent. (and sure, I could calculate the value, but that's not the point of the percent pie series - it should format the numbers itself)

Comment: You actually do have the `valuePercentTotal`. It means the "percentage of the total", which is what you want to display. I updated my answer so you can see that it is actually what you need.

Comment: (Note: due to rounding, the percentages add up to 99%, but this is a well know mathematical problem.): https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody/problems/44545-percentages-may-not-total-100-due-to-rounding

Answer (score 1):

I used @SelVazi's answer and called the `series.labels.template.set` function, providing a different `format`. Instead of `{valuePercentTotal.formatNumber('#.p')}`, I used `{value.formatNumber('#,###')}`.

Instead of displaying the percent, the code snippet displays the actual value following the format `#,###`. I changed the values to be in thousands so it would appear to have the thousand-separator. I also modified the tooltip to show the % of total.

```html
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/percent.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
am5.ready(function() {

// Create root element
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");


// Set themes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

// Create chart
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/
var chart = root.container.children.push(am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
  layout: root.verticalLayout
}));

// Create series
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Series
var series = chart.series.push(am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
  valueField: "value",
  categoryField: "category"
}));


series.labels.template.set("text", 
    "{category}: {value.formatNumber('#,###')}");
    
series.slices.template.set("tooltipText", 
    "{category}: {valuePercentTotal.formatNumber('#.p')}");


// Set data
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Setting_data
series.data.setAll([
  { value: 1000, category: "One" },
  { value: 9000, category: "Two" },
  { value: 6000, category: "Three" },
  { value: 5000, category: "Four" },
  { value: 4000, category: "Five" },
  { value: 3000, category: "Six" },
  { value: 1000, category: "Seven" },
]);


// Play initial series animation
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/#Animation_of_series
series.appear(1000, 100);

}); // end am5.ready()
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is by modify contents of the text using text setting on a series label template:

```
series.labels.template.set("text", 
    "{category}: {valuePercentTotal.formatNumber('#.p')}");
```

We can also modify contents of the tooltips using tooltipText on slice's template:

```
series.slices.template.set("tooltipText", 
    "{category}: {valuePercentTotal.formatNumber('#.p')}");
```

`p` stands for percentage symbol.

[Docs here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/pie-series/#label-content)

```html
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/percent.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
am5.ready(function() {

// Create root element
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");


// Set themes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

//root.numberFormatter.set("numberFormat", "00,000");

// Create chart
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/
var chart = root.container.children.push(am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
  layout: root.verticalLayout
}));

// Create series
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Series
var series = chart.series.push(am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
  valueField: "value",
  categoryField: "category"
}));


series.labels.template.set("text", 
    "{category}: {valuePercentTotal.formatNumber('#.p')}");
    
series.slices.template.set("tooltipText", 
    "{category}: {valuePercentTotal.formatNumber('#.p')}");


// Set data
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Setting_data
series.data.setAll([
  { value: 10, category: "One" },
  { value: 9, category: "Two" },
  { value: 6, category: "Three" },
  { value: 5, category: "Four" },
  { value: 4, category: "Five" },
  { value: 3, category: "Six" },
  { value: 1, category: "Seven" },
]);


// Play initial series animation
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/#Animation_of_series
series.appear(1000, 100);

}); // end am5.ready()
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```